# How to click Radio Button using python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, radio-button

I am trying to Click the Radio Button "Monthly (Final)" in the left side tab.

Please find the link https://socds.huduser.gov/permits/index.html?

Here is the Code which i tried,

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

chrome_path = r"/usr/bin/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("https://www.huduser.gov/portal/datasets/socds.html") # Hitting the Site
driver.maximize_window()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="block-system-main"]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/form[5]/input""").click() #Clicking Buiding Permits Database
time.sleep(10)
### Not working ###
print driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/form/a[2]/input""").location # Getting the Location of the Element
Radio = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/form/a[2]/input""") # Clicking Monthly Final Radio button
Radio.click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body > form:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(29) > input:nth-child(1)").click()
print "DONE"
```

Comment: Please mention the issue in you question not in comments of your code. you haven't mentioned what is going wrong exactly.

Comment: you have used `" " "`  in your xpath. `" " "` is treated as comments.

Comment: @PrakashPalnati, `"""string"""` is not a comment, but a simple string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Radio button located inside an `iframe`. To be able to click it you should swith to `iframe` first:

```
driver.switch_to.frame('select')
Radio = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//input[@value="monthlyF"]""")
Radio.click()
```

Comment: How did you get that as XPath. My XPath was different

Comment: I just write my own while I guess you get it with browser dev console or other tool. You need to [improve your skills in writing your own relative XPath expressions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xpath/index.htm) as using absolute XPath that online tool generated for you is bad practice...